# How did Beale know about the Saudi Arabian deal?

Tags: plot-explanation, network

In the movie [Network](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074958/), Beale knows that there's a deal between a Saudi Arabian company and CCA?

Many of the staff don't know anything about the deal. How does Beale know?